# How to add new line to existing txt file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am a completely new to bash scripting. I have a txt file (call it `geom.txt`) which I am using which looks like this:

```
2
C -0.6165934086165 -0.35599823933468 0.00000000 0.8466
C 0.6165934086165 0.35599823933468 0.00000000 0.8466
lattice_vector 2.46670923 0.00000000 0.00000000
lattice_vector 1.23286602 2.13599798 0.00000000
lattice_vector 0.00000000 0.00000000 40
```

I would like to write a script which will add a line between lines 1 and 2 to produce an output like:

```
2

C -0.6165934086165 -0.35599823933468 0.00000000 0.8466
C 0.6165934086165 0.35599823933468 0.00000000 0.8466
lattice_vector 2.46670923 0.00000000 0.00000000
lattice_vector 1.23286602 2.13599798 0.00000000
lattice_vector 0.00000000 0.00000000 40
```

Furthermore, I want to make this general so that any input file of the previous form will add an empty line between lines 1 and 2.  I know this is basic, but I need help! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `gnu sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '2s/^/\n/' file
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==2{print "\n" $0; next}1' file
```

Using `non-gnu sed`

```
sed -i.bak $'2s/^/\\\n/' file
```

OR else:

```
eol=$'\n'
sed -i.bak "2s/^/\\$eol/" file
```

Finally here is pure BASH way:

```
c=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    (( c++ == 1 )) && echo
    echo "$line"
done < file
```

Comment: Probably it was for offering more than one solution. `:P`

Comment: @jaypal does SO won't allow more than one solution in a single answer? I think he don't want to chat with the OP. So that only he posted sed solutions for differnt types of sed. And `+1` for this advance thinking.

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj, buddy Jaypal was saying that in lighter vein, there is no rule that says one can't more than one solution in same answer :)

Comment: +1, but it's worth noting that looping over lines of an input file in pure shell code is rarely the right solution for performance reasons. That said, `[[ $c == 1 ]] && echo ...  ... ((c++))` can be simplified to `(( c++ == 1 )) && echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it in a simple while loop:

```
let count=0   # set a simple integer to test
:> tmpfile    # create or truncate tmpfile

while read line || test -n "$line"; do
    echo "$line" >> tmpfile   # write each line to tmpfile
    # if this is the first line, add a newline and increment counter
    test "$count" -eq 0 && echo "" >> tmpfile && ((count+=1))
done <"$1"

# when all lines written to tmpfile copy tmpfile to filename given as arg, remove tmpfile
cp tmpfile "$1" && rm -f tmpfile
```

Comment: There is no advantage to using `let` with `count=0` - with or without `let` `count` will be a string variable; if you want to create an _integer_ variable, use `declare -i count=0` (which will similarly clarify your intent). Note, though, that thanks to duck typing the type rarely matters. In using `((...))` you've already committed to non-POSIX `bash` syntax, so why not use `[[ ... ]]` or `((...))` instead of `test`? E.g., `test "$count" -eq 0 && echo "" >> tmpfile && ((count+=1))` could be simplified to `(( count++ == 0 )) && echo >> tmpfile`.

Comment: Also, the general caveat applies that looping over lines of an input file in pure shell code is inadvisable for performance reasons - a utility such as `sed` or `awk` is much, much faster.

Comment: @mklement0 Both points well taken. The value of a variable is evaluated as an arithmetic expression `when it is referenced`, **or** when a variable which has been given the integer attribute `using declare -i` is assigned a value. (man bash) Agreed, whether declared -i or not, it rarely matters. Looping through may have its drawbacks for large files, but for anything less that a few thousand lines, the loop with be as quick, or quicker, than launching an additional app to do it.

Comment: Actually, I just ran a quick test comparing your solution against a `sed`-based one (`sed $'2s/^/\\\n/' file`): The `sed` solution starts to be faster at around _50_ lines (of the same length as the sample data in the question, on my OS X 10.9.4 system). Not a scientific test, but it gives you a sense that the threshold is probably lower than you think. While I agree that it won't matter for small files, it's generally worth adding a performance disclaimer when posting a shell-only loop-over-lines solution. Re your specific code: you must double-quote `$line` in `test -n $line`.

Comment: Now that is a good test. I haven't had time to run it, but I suspect the results will vary from say 50 as you found up to a thousand or so depending on disk layout, cache, etc. `sed` with a single call from the command line has little to slow it down, but if called repeatedly say from within a script, any advantage rapidly disappears. Thanks for taking time to put numbers to it. If I find anything remarkable, I shall drop a note here.

Comment: Thanks. Re "but if [sed is] called repeatedly say from within a script": The very point of the test was to _juxtapose_ a _single_ sed invocation with an equivalent looping shell-only solution - _because the former can replace the latter_, as in this case. What you're describing is the worst of both worlds: combining a shell loop with an external invocation in every iteration.

Comment: Re `test -n $line`: your script goes into an _infinite loop_ due to lack of double-quoting, because after the last line read - at which `$line` is empty - `test -n $line` evalutes to just `test -n`, which is always true (without an argument, `-n` is not recognized as an _operator_; it is treated as a _string_, and since that string is nonempty, the test is true).

Comment: You can remove it as long as there is a new line following the last line of text. That's all it is there for. In fact, since we are not reading from a file, is shouldn't be there. Excellent catch.

Comment: No No, you can't. What was mission was redirection of filename into the for loop. The test construct requires quoting. It's early here :)

Comment: :) Thanks for updating. The test for a missing trailing newline is a handy tool to have in one's toolbox. Going back to the earlier point about `test` vs. `[[...]]`: the equivalent statement is `while read line || [[ -n $line ]];` - it will rarely matter in the real world, but it's interesting to note that using `[[` is almost twice as fast as `test`, especially when _not_ double-quoting variable references inside `[[ ... ]]` - which you _can_ get away with due to different parsing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vim` to achieve your goal.

```
vim -c 1 -c "normal o" -c wq geom.txt
```